# Can this 'Idownload' html download link be used with PowerShell script automate download process?

Tags: powershell, download

My end goal is to use PowerShell to download a zip file from a website that first requires one to  login through the initial page. A simple powershell script example I have found is the following:

```
# URL and Destination
$url = "https://example.com/reports/test.zip"
$dest = "c:\temp\testfiles"
# Define username and password
$username = 'User1'
$password = 'Password123'
# Convert to SecureString
$secPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
# Create Credential Object
$credObject = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $secPassword)
# Download file
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $dest -Credential $credObject
```

My main concern is the html download link I get from the zip file I am actually downloading. The link goes like: https://example.com/webclient/idownload (the actual link does end in /webclient/idownload). I have not seen an answer as to what the 'idownload' extension means in terms of types of download links. Is this some type of secure download link where the download item name is not in the html like many standard download links: https://example.com/reports/test.zip. There are multiple download links on the webpage, and I find that the html link is exactly the same for all downloads, all ending with 'idownload', even though the download files themselves have different names.
Overall I am looking to gain insight into this type of download link I am dealing with, and how I can effectively automate the download process with a PowerShell script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have kind of a similar case and this works for me. Please update accordingly your situation

```
#variables
$url = "https://blah/../../file_to_download"
$output = "c:\...\file.zip" #local path including filename

$SecretFile = "c:\....\securestring.txt"

#Uncomment following line to create the secretfile
#Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString | convertfrom-securestring | out-file $SecretFile
$Username = "user"

#downloading data
$wc = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$credCache = new-object System.Net.CredentialCache
$creds = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username,(Get-Content $SecretFile | ConvertTo-SecureString))
$credCache.Add($url, "Basic", $creds)

$wc.Credentials = $credCache
$wc.DownloadFile($url, $output)
```

Comment: This should work however my main problem is that i cannot find a unique download link url. All download links on the page end in 'idownload' making it so that they are not unique. Are you dealing with a case as such also?

Comment: Ther must be smthg make teh difference between each link, no ????

Comment: I cannot find that yet. I think it what is making the unique download links must be hidden or secure from someone like me visiting the webpage and going through the source code.